# How to list all my contributions

Tags: discussion

I like to list all the questions I involved but each question should listed only once. If I want to see a list where I contributed a comment, answer or question I have to go to `all actions`. There for I get a list where each entry represents a action and I want a list like this, but destinct this list by questions.

Comment: Do you want the list to show you which of these actions you have taken, or is a list of all the questions you have asked or answered or where you have commented on a post sufficient? How about edits -- should questions you have edited (or edited an answer to) be included? I'm not sure precisely what your requirements are, but I expect the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/queries) should enable you to query effectively for what you are looking for.

Comment: @EliahKagan The second one, just want a list with all posts I'm involved (I'm not care about edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible through vanilla StackExchange, but I've gone ahead and created a [quick-n-dirty SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/618957/find-all-questions-ive-touched) query that will show you most of your actions on-site. It will display one entry for each of:

- Questions Posted
- Answers Posted
- Comments to a Question
- Comments to an Answer
- Edits to a Question
- Edits to an Answer

Simply click on that, enter your User ID, and hit <kbd>Run Query</kbd>. You can get your user ID by looking at your profile page's URL. It'll be the number embedded after `users/`:

```
https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/613613/h%C3%B6lderlin
```

Meaning, your user ID is `613613`.

---

Now, something to quickly note about SE Data Explorer. It only updates once a week, specifically 3 AM UTC on Sunday. This means that the data returned by the query given above will not be up-to-date, but will still give you a good idea of what's going on.

Comment: Thx you get it, although I used the wrong term if I said "unify" I mean "unique" (distinct). I'm not care about edits like [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/revision/619187/773750/unify-actions)

Comment: If you want a list of questions you've answered, commented, asked, or commented on an answer, try [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/619435/find-all-questions-ive-touched-redux).